# TFS Warehouse / Coverage Analysis failing

Tags: tfs, build, code-coverage, tfsbuild

I am running with TFS 2015.3, and SQL Server 2016 SP1, in separate servers.

Recently, I change our production TFS Database from 32 bit to 64 bit (for updating purposes), and I believe we loose some database configuration and permissions.

This week (after the change), we are having some issues with some Jobs, related to Warehouse and Coverage Analysis:

[Screenshot of Failing Jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqAKw.png)

The error that is shown is:

Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.DatabaseOperationTimeoutException: TF246018: The database operation exceeded the timeout limit and has been cancelled. Verify that the parameters of the operation are correct. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.ExecuteCommand(ExecuteType executeType, CommandBehavior behavior) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.TranslateException(Int32 errorNumber, SqlException sqlException, SqlError sqlError) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.TranslateException(SqlException sqlException) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.MapException(SqlException ex, QueryExecutionState queryState) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.HandleException(Exception exception) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.ExecuteCommand(ExecuteType executeType, CommandBehavior behavior) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.CircuitBreaker.Command.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__0() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.CircuitBreaker.CommandAsync.d__28.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.CircuitBreaker.Command.Execute(Action run, Action fallback) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.ExecuteCommandWithBaseCircuitBreaker(ExecuteType executeType, CommandBehavior behavior) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean bindReturnValue) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.ExecuteNonQuery() at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Server.BuildCoverage.Update(TestManagementRequestContext context, Int32 coverageChangeId) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Server.Jobs.CoverageAnalyzer.AnalyzeBuild(BuildInfo buildInfo, String& resultMessage) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Server.Jobs.CoverageAnalyzer.Run(String& resultMessage) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Server.Jobs.CoverAnJob.Run(IVssRequestContext requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime queueTime, String& resultMessage)

And also I got this one for another job:

[Test Management Warehouse Sync]: ---> MakeDataChanges() result=DataChangesPending. ---> MakeDataChanges() result=DataChangesPending. ---> MakeDataChanges() result=DataChangesPending. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseException: TF221122: An error occurred running job Test Management Warehouse Sync for team project collection or Team Foundation server Product. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.DatabaseOperationCanceledException: TF53001: The database operation was canceled by an administrator. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded. Operation cancelled by user. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.ExecuteCommand(ExecuteType executeType, CommandBehavior behavior) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.TranslateException(SqlException sqlException) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.MapException(SqlException ex, QueryExecutionState queryState) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.HandleException(Exception exception) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.ExecuteCommand(ExecuteType executeType, CommandBehavior behavior) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean bindReturnValue) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseBatchedDataAccessComponent.ExecuteNonQuery() at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Warehouse.TeamTestWarehouseAdapter.SaveBatchesToWarehouse() at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Warehouse.TeamTestWarehouseAdapter.ProcessResults(WarehouseRowVersionQueryDelegate query, String highWaterMarkProperty, String processLimitProperty) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Warehouse.TeamTestWarehouseAdapter.MakeDataChanges() at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseSyncJobExtension`1.MakeDataChanges(IVssRequestContext requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, String& resultMessage) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseSyncJobExtension`1.RunInternal(IVssRequestContext requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime queueTime, String& resultMessage) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseJobExtension.Run(IVssRequestContext requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime queueTime, String& resultMessage) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I am guessing this is due to a Database error, but I can't get to the bottom of it. I am using the TFS for automated Builds, and I am not able to see the Code Coverage for the most recent builds. I don't know if it is related. I went to the Application Tier, and Start a Rebuild for the Reporting services, and that works for some of the Build (the Code Coverage appears), but for the newer builds, it is not happening as expected (I run the Rebuild and still the Code Coverage is not shown).

[Code Coverage not shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kybA6.png)

Do you have any ideas on what is going on with those jobs? How can I solve this?

Thank you so much in advance. If you need any further information, please let me know.

Comment: The issue with code coverage is totally unrelated. The build system doesn't interact with the warehouse.

Comment: How did you change the production TFS Database from 32 bit to 64 bit ? Did you just upgrade SQL Server from 32bit to 64bit? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55030/how-to-move-from-32bit-sql-server-install-to-64bit

Comment: Did you get those issues resolved already? If not, do [Test Management Warehouse Sync] and [Work Item Tracking Warehouse Sync] are still having the very same stack traces, or they have changed a bit over time? If you could you re-post them, so we can see the new stack traces there?

Comment: In a case that your Test Management Warehouse Sync job, continue to fail due to a timeout, please take a look below, for a possible resolution:
https://dankovalkov.wordpress.com/2017/02/03/tfs-2017-resolving-tf221122-tf246018-tf400307-and-tf400797-issues/